# Since when does null.toString() return [object Null]?

Tags: javascript

I'm curious, becouse i thought that

```
Object.prototype.toString.call(null)
```

return `[object Object]`, but now i was checking that in Chrome and FF and both returned `[object Null]`. Now the question is, wether i can assume that Object.prototype.toString will always tell me the good type?

Until now, i was checking every type with this method, but not for null values, i was checking null values by

```
obj === null;
```

Thanks!

---

Note for clarification: this 'problem' is not a serious case, since atm i'm using

```
function isNull(obj) {
  return obj === null;
}

function isUndefined(obj) {
  return typeof obj === 'undefined';  
}
```

which works just fine, but if `Object.prototype.toString.call()` would work sufficient in older browsers, i could drop these two functions and extend my solution with `null` and `undefined` like:

```js
var types = ['Object', 'Number', 'String', 'Array', 'Function', 
 'Date', 'RegExp', 'Boolean', 'Error', 'Null', 'Undefined'].reduce(function(prev, type) {
    prev['[object ' + type + ']'] = type.toLowerCase();
 return prev;
  }, {});

function isType(type) {
  return function(obj) {
 return getType(obj) === type;
  };
}

function getType(obj) {
  return types[Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)];
}

var isNull = isType('null');

document.querySelector('#console').textContent = isNull(null);
```

```html
<div id='console'></div>
```

Comment: And why would you need to check for every type ?

Comment: here is from FF:
`Starting in JavaScript 1.8.5 toString() called on null returns [object Null], and undefined returns [object Undefined] ...`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius it's not that weird if you read the documentation.

Comment: And here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString#Using_toString_to_detect_object_type

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius: Which browser (version)? `Object.prototype.toString.apply("hello")` gives `"[object String]"` for me in Chrome and FF.

Comment: @FelixKling Never mind, I was being stupid. I'll delete the comment.

Comment: Also: http://es5.github.io/#x15.2.4.2

Comment: Thanks for the comments and aswers, then new question, if i would like to support older browsers and environments, can i use toString to check for null and undefined, or its something that legacy browsers can't use?
Now i do obj === null for isNull() and typeof obj === 'undefined' for isUndefined(). If {}.toString would work for older browsers, i would drop these two methods.

Comment: @Jim-Y Why do you want to use `toString` to check for null and undefined instead of just `typeof` or direct comparison?

Comment: I'm already using a terse ~way~ for checking values, and if toString would work efficient on null and undefined, then i could drop 2 unnecessary functions :) Not a serious case, but you know, i was curious :)

Answer (score 4):

This is defined in [EcmaScript 5.1 Section 15.2.4.2 - `Object.prototype.toString()`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.4.2):

> When the `toString` method is called, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. If the `this` value is `undefined`, return `"[object Undefined]"`.
> 2. If the `this` value is `null`, return `"[object Null]"`.
> 3. Let `O` be the result of calling `ToObject` passing the `this` value as the argument.
> 4. Let `class` be the value of the `[[Class]]` internal property of `O`.
> 5. Return the String value that is the result of concatenating the three Strings `"[object "`, `class`, and `"]"`.

[EcmaScript 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262%205th%20edition%20December%202009.pdf) defined it differently:

> When the `toString` method is called, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. Let `O` be the result of calling `ToObject` passing the `this` value as the argument.
> 2. Let `class` be the value of the `[[Class]]` internal property of `O`.
> 3. Return the String value that is the result of concatenating the three Strings `"[object "`, `class`, and `"]"`.

Answer (score 4):

Oriol's answer is right, but I wanted to add that there is a difference between calling `toString` directly on, say, a number or a string, vs. using `Object.prototype.toString`.

The `Object.prototype.toString` function is general, so if we do

```
var x = "hello, world";
alert(Object.prototype.toString.call(x));
```

we will see "[Object string]".

However, if we call toString directly, instead, like this:

```
alert(x.toString());
```

we will see "hello, world". The reason for this is that `toString` in the second example is really `String.prototype.toString`, which is different from the generic `Object.prototype.toString` method. The same distinction occurs with a number like 6:

```
var y = 6;
alert(Object.prototype.toString.call(y)); // "[Object Number]"
alert(y.toString()); // "6"
alert(Number.prototype.toString.call(y)); // also "6"
```

In this case, the primitive value 6 is being boxed into an instance of `Number` when you do `y.toString()`. When you concatenate strings, it's the object's `toString` method that gets called, not `Object.prototype.toString`, which is why `alert("I am " + y + " years old")` produces "I am 6 years old", not "I am [Object Number] years old".

Since `null` has no `Null` prototype or anything like that, doing `null.toString()` will produce an error.

Comment: Thanks, but the original question was far from this answer, but, thanks anyway ^^