# Why can't I call a method on null if its type is "object"?

Tags: javascript

I'm curious why in javascript the following code is returning an error:

```
null.toString()
```

where in other languages such as ruby, it renders the "logical" empty string:

```
nil.to_s # ""
```

I was curious about the behaviour since:

```
typeof null == "object"
```

So I thought it would make sense to have the prototype toString() "attached" to it. It seems `typeof null` returns `object` only for legacy reasons: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null

Comment: javascript isn't ruby.

Comment: Because that's the way the language was designed. The value `null` is not an object reference, so it makes no sense (in JavaScript) to access any properties.

Comment: *Most* languages will throw some sort of error when trying to work with `null` as an object. Ruby really is the outlier here.

Comment: how else would you disinguish empty string and nothing?

Comment: @Daniel `typeof something`…!? `something === ''`…!? That's not really an argument.

Comment: Your downvotes are stupid guys, that's a real question and I want to know what was the design decision around it.

Comment: um @deceze - `typeof null == 'object'`

Comment: @Daniel Yeah, but `typeof '' == 'string'`…

Comment: @JeremieGes you will have to ask the designers of the languages.

Comment: @deceze well what if you wanted to know if you actually had an object, not null. i'm just making the case that we have null for that case.

Comment: More technically speaking: `nil` in Ruby is an object like any other object, `null` in Javascript is a primitive type and not an object. *Why* that was designed that way we cannot tell you, it just was. We can make arguments for or against those decisions, but in the end it simply *was* and that's that.

Comment: @DanielA.White you answer is not constructive at all. This guy is asking about language design and why when you scratch the surface it behaves in a specific way. Giving an example from another language it for us to understand why it could make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`null` is a primitive value and cause that you can’t call `toString` function.  Only objects provide toString from prototype.  Basically, primitive values don’t have properties.

**Why typeof null is object?**

> You know, this all came about because of rushing in early May 1995, which led to a leak of type tag representation shared by null and object types. But null means "no object", so it didn't raise hackles until it was too late to fix in Netscape 2, and after that we were loath to "fix" it and "break the web". That argument only applies more in degree of web population now. We have other fish to fry. This one was has been swallowed already. Let's not change typeof null for ES4 and work on more vital issues. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28956144/1715121)

Another good resource: [typeof UnaryExpression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18808252/1715121)

Comment: Thank you Ele, that was exactly the kind of answer I was waiting for!

Answer (score 2):

`null` is a "primitive value" and the `.toString()` is defined in the JavaScript Object's Prototypes. Therefore this can't work.

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null

Comment: I like your answer, but why typeof null returns "object"

Comment: this is because of the way JavaScript is designed. `The value null is written with a literal: null. null is not an identifier for a property of the global object, like undefined can be. Instead, null expresses a lack of identification, indicating that a variable points to no object.`. Check the second link, there is a good explanation for this behaviour

Comment: typeof null  // "object" (not "null" for legacy reasons), okay now it makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const stringValue = someObject.someValue ? someObject.someValue.toString() : null;
```

In case `someObject.someValue` has a type `number | null`

Answer (score 0):

We cannot call instance method `ToString()` on a  `null` reference. How can we call not declared function or property in class/object/reference,etc. It simply show an error *property `toString`  does not exist not type `null`*

It dependent on language:

- Javascript - `null.toString()` -  run time error
- TypeScript - `null.toString()` - not allow to declare
- C# - `null.toString()` not allow to declare  (But in c# you can convert by `Convert.ToString(null);` and it will return `""`)
- [More](https://www.google.co.in/search?dcr=0&ei=NLt5WqKjFYGLvQSQiYKgCw&q=null.tostring%28%29&oq=null.tostring%28%29&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39k1j0j0i30k1l4j0i10i30k1j0i30k1l2.136105.534240.0.534611.18.13.2.0.0.0.586.2180.0j1j3j2j0j1.8.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..8.10.2418.6..0i67k1j0i20i263k1.234.zHngcjATv5M)

### Edit: why typeof null returns "object"

[Since when does null.toString() return [object Null]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25895756/since-when-does-null-tostring-return-object-null?rq=1)

Comment: FWIW, Typescript === Javascript in this regard…

Comment: @deceze Yeah! java-script allow to declare.  But typescript shows error while declare it

Answer (score 0):

[null](/questions/tagged/null) is not an object or an identifier to one. Since `.toString()` is an object prototype, they are incompatible with each other and will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

- In JavaScript everything except `null` and `undefined` can behave like an object.
- `toString` is `method`.
- `method` is function inside object.

So since `null` can never behave like an `object` you can't apply any method.